# Show different adsense block based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I am trying to find a way that works with twitter bootstrap's responsive design to show different adverts based on screen size.

Previously I was just sticking three different adverts inside "hidden-desktop" "hidden-tablet" and "hidden-phone", although researching it now i've found it they will all still be counted as while they may be "hidden" they are still running.

Has anyone found a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less efficient, but simple way would be to use javascript to dynamically load your adverts. 
On page load, check which class tag is visible and then load the appropriate ad.

You lose on SEO, but since 99.99% adverts are also loaded in runtime by JS anyway, this won't affect you at all. + You probably don't want SEO from adverts anyway, so no problem there.